# Get method which is undefined in interface in java

Tags: java, interface

I have an interface "Messenger", which defines 4 methods. Then in "MessengerEng" class, I inherit "Messenger" interface and also add one undefined method "msgExample".
Question: How to access "msgExample" method (which is not defined in "Messenger" interface) ?

Comment: Cast it. Although you may want to ask yourself why that is necessary as it maybe defeats the point of programming to the interface.

Comment: If your reference object is only of type `Messanger`, then you cannot (not without casting / reflection etc). If you show us an example of what you're talking about, we might possibly be able to offer an alternative suggestion, since I have a feeling your scenario could be solved with a slight design tweak.

Comment: @BoristheSpider - it is necessary, because it is one of my assignment points. Maybe you could give me an example of how to do it?

Comment: "Then in "MessengerEng" class, I inherit "Messenger" interface and also add one undefined method "msgExample"" -- Are you implementing Messenger interface or you are extending Messenger interface in MessengerEng?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could cast it to the desired type. For example:

```
Messenger msg = new MessengerEng();
((MessengerEng) msg).methodNotInterface();
```

This is an unsafe cast though, so use it carefully if at all.

Comment: if(msg instance of MessengerEng) should help.

Answer (score 0):

You must have a pointer to a MessengerEng in order to access the msgExample method since this is the highest object reference that can contain that function.

Answer (score 0):

I've an example.Pl read & tell me if thats what you want to do.

```
interface Messenger{
public void Method1outof4();
}
class MessengerEng implements Messenger{
    public void Method1outof4(){
    System.out.println("Interface method");
}
public void msgExample(){
    System.out.println("Non-Interface method");
}
}
class testInterface{
public static void main(String[] args){
    MessengerEng m = new MessengerEng();
    m.Method1outof4();
    m.msgExample();
}
}
```